# Onsenui wont work with SVG progress bar

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I am trying to add a simple circular progress chart (https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar) but it doesnt seem to work with Onsenui. Im using Onsen v1.3.8 - 2015-07-27.

I added the script correctly and also added 'angular-svg-round-progress' to my modules... so really struggling to figure out whats wrong...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com https://*.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://*.phonegap.com https://*.googleapis.com https://*.cloudflare.com http://*.elasticbeanstalk.com https://*.monaca.mobi:8080 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/roundProgress.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       var app =  ons.bootstrap();
    </script> 
    <script> angular.module('app',  ['onsen','angular-svg-round-progress'])</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cortisol.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">



</head>
<body>
<ons-page>
    <ons-tabbar position="top"  >
      <ons-tabbar-item page="dashboard.html" style="margin-top:20px"><span style="margin-top:20px"><img src="img/icon.svg" width="34"/></span></ons-tabbar-item>
      <ons-tabbar-item page="dashboard.html"  icon="ion-ios-pulse-strong" active="true"  class="tab-bar__button tab-bar--top-border__button"></ons-tabbar-item>
      <ons-tabbar-item page="timeline.html"  icon="ion-android-calendar"></ons-tabbar-item>
      <ons-tabbar-item page="capture.html"  icon="ion-pinpoint"></ons-tabbar-item> 
      <ons-tabbar-item page="settings.html"  icon="ion-android-settings"></ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>

</body>
</html>
```

Page:

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar fixed-style>
        <div class="center">Dashboard</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-row style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;" >
        <ons-col >

        <div
    round-progress
    max="max"
    current="current"
    color="#45ccce"
    bgcolor="#eaeaea"
    radius="100"
    stroke="20"
    semi="true"
    rounded="true"
    clockwise="false"
    responsive="false"
    duration="800"
    animation="easeInOutQuart"
    animation-delay="0"></div>

        </ons-col> 
    </ons-row>
  </ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not load the module in your the app variable, but in some other angular environment.

```
var app =  ons.bootstrap('app',  ['onsen','angular-svg-round-progress']);
```

should do the trick. Here is a working codepen script: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZEmEy.